# Mysqli_query view the last image for all user

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with mysqli_query. When last user upload image, all user have last image.

This code that I have write:

```
        <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($soci->con, "SELECT soci.*, (SELECT full_path FROM soci_media WHERE id = soci.immagine_profilo) AS immagine_profilo_file FROM soci");
        while($socio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 single_socio pb-3">
                <?php if($soci->user_data['immagine_profilo_file'] == '') { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/test/images/user.png" alt="" class="default_image img-fluid" />
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/uploads<?php echo $soci->user_data['immagine_profilo_file']; ?>" alt="" class="default_image img-fluid" />
                <?php } ?>
                <h2><?php echo $socio['nome']; ?> <?php echo $socio['cognome']; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

[Screenshot table database and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sA3V.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to retrieve from that query? The problem is coming from your SQL or your PHP logic?

Comment: @Chemaclass `$soci->user_data['immagine_profilo_file']` is evidently a php logic

Comment: I think problem is in my php logic, how I can resolve?

Comment: I am wondering why do you have `$socio` and `$soci` variables? Is it a typo? Or it is intentional?

Comment: Is intentional...if i change all $socio into $soci not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the select clause to do another query (it will not work). You should join the tables. I used a left join to avoid not having values if there is no profile image.

```
    SELECT soci.*,soci_media.full_path AS immagine_profilo_file 
    FROM soci
    LEFT JOIN soci_media ON soci.immagine_profilo = soci_media.id
```

You need to replace your query like this:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($soci->con, "SELECT soci.*,soci_media.full_path AS immagine_profilo_file FROM soci LEFT JOIN soci_media ON soci.immagine_profilo = soci_media.id");
```

In addition you need to assign the current variables:

```
while($socio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 single_socio pb-3">
        <?php if($socio['immagine_profilo_file'] == '') { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/test/images/user.png" alt="" class="default_image img-fluid" />
        <?php } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/uploads<?php echo $socio['immagine_profilo_file']; ?>" alt="" class="default_image img-fluid" />
        <?php } ?>
        <h2><?php echo $socio['nome']; ?> <?php echo $socio['cognome']; ?></h2>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Just updated the answer, correct your variables in while loop